# GDI is drawing outside of control

Tags: mfc, controls, gdi

I'm programming an MFC application. I created a CStatic derived control on my Form dialog, so that I see the form directly when starting the program. I'm now drawing in this control with the OnPaint() Method in the derived class. So far, everything works. 
However, strangely the drawings aren't clipped outside of the control. Instead,the whole form is painted if I draw really big things. In my understanding, only the control should be painted.

Thanks in advance
Andreas D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your control is using the 'Unclipped Device Context' option. You can check this by getting the control flags.
You can also call IsOptimizedDraw() and if that return true then your drawing can draw outside the control.

Answer (score 2):

@dlb Got it now.

```
CDC* pDC = GetDC();
CRect rClient();
GetClientRect(rClient);
CRgn ClipRgn;
if (ClipRgn.CreateRectRgnIndirect(&rClient))
{
    pDC->SelectClipRgn(&ClipRgn);
}


// Drawing content


pDC->SelectClipRgn(NULL);
ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Though My issue was not mentioned above but "CDC* pDC = GetDC();" resolve my issue ... Thanks @Andreas